# Tracking visitor stats with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, statistics, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Are there any visitor statistics solutions for Ruby on Rails?

I'm talking something like Google Analytics, but without passing data through a third party.

I'd like to track such parameters as visitor count, visit depth, bounce rate, referer (by host or by GET parameter), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.scribd.com/doc/49575/Scaling-Rails-Presentation

There is a section in there on baked in analytics.  There are things you need baked in analytics to do (like using such statistics on widgets for your site).

You should supplement this with Google Analytics if you in any way can, as it is much better than anything that you could hack together quickly.  I wouldn't get hung up on the third party issue as everyone uses it.